# Android camera preview Image is rotated by 180 after opening the camera via Intent

Tags: android, android-camera

I am using intents to launch the camera app on Android. The problem is on Samsung Note 9 I am seeing that the preview images is rotated upside down. However the bitmap obtained in onActivityResult is fine.
I want to fix the preview image screen using the Intent approach.

```
private fun dispatchTakePictureIntent() {
        Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE).also { takePictureIntent ->
            takePictureIntent.resolveActivity(packageManager)?.also {
                startActivityForResult(takePictureIntent, REQUEST_IMAGE_CAPTURE)
            }
        }

    }

override fun onActivityResult(requestCode: Int, resultCode: Int, data: Intent?) {
        if (requestCode == REQUEST_IMAGE_CAPTURE && resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
            val imageBitmap = data?.extras?.get("data") as Bitmap

            ivTest.setImageBitmap(imageBitmap)
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, but you have no means of controlling the preview behavior of a third-party camera app.